# How to get message replies from Telegram groups by API - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

I am trying to fetch the replies to the messages in a channel. For example: if my post has 60 replies ("discussion" as mentioned in the app) in channel X (let's say 1555671526), I need to fetch all those 60 reply messages along with the original post.

As of now I'm trying:

```
# using get_messages
channel_id = 1555671526 # it is sample channel (random)
message = client.get_messages(channel_id)
reply = message.get_reply_message()
print(reply)

# using iter_messages
for m in client.iter_messages(c):
    print(m.get_reply_message())
```

I understand if there are no replies, get_reply_message will return None and it is returning None in both cases. However, I can see that there are replies to the post.

Can someone suggest to me how to fetch the reply messages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tags have descriptions. Please read them before using unrelated tags ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
channel_id = 1555671526
replies = []
for message in client.iter_messages(channel_id):
    for reply in message.iter_replies():
        replies.append(reply)
print(replies)
```

You should also check whether the channel is public or private, as the bot must join private channels before it may fetch messages.

Comment: The `filter` in `iter_messages` doesn't support arbitrary lambdas, so this solution will unfortunately not work.